# java.security.AccessControlException: Access Denied Error

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, runtime

I created a simple webservice to my web application. When im trying to access the wsdl file, I get this error. Does someone know why am I getting error?

> 18:44:39,420 ERROR [io.undertow.request] UT005023: Exception handling
>   request to /dC/Hello: java.security.AccessControlException: access
>   denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "org.jboss.as.server.LOOKUP_CURRENT_SERVICE_CONTAINER")   at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_161]    at
>   java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_161]    at
>   org.jboss.as.server.CurrentServiceContainer.checkPermission(CurrentServiceContainer.java:64)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.CurrentServiceContainer.getServiceContainer(CurrentServiceContainer.java:52)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.webservices.util.ASHelper.getMSCService(ASHelper.java:382)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.webservices.util.ServiceContainerEndpointRegistry.getEndpoint(ServiceContainerEndpointRegistry.java:65)
>     at
>   org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.initServiceEndpoint(ServletHelper.java:79)
>     at
>   org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.initEndpoint(ServletHelper.java:67)
>     at
>   org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.loadBus(CXFServletExt.java:68)
>     at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.init(CXFServletExt.java:62)
>     at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.init(WSFServlet.java:57)
>   [jbossws-spi-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:79)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:220)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.getServlet(ManagedServlet.java:163)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:84)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:129)
>   [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:162)
>   [javamelody-core.jar:1.59.0]  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]   at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]   at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]   at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]   at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1$1.run(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_161]    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:169)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]    at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]   at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
>   [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_161]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_161]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_161]

Comment: Please delete your image and paste the error message as text into your question.

Comment: Your error is unreadable to me

Comment: i cant post image as i need 10 reputations to post images :(

Comment: Perdon please? Go to your browser, use your mouse. Copy the text into the clipboard. After that click on edit link underneath your question and paste the content from your clipboard into this.

Comment: A shoot into the dark: The vm of java is started with a user who has different permissions as the file owner.

Comment: @reporterhow how do i get this Hello class to be able get the permission from the java vm itself? can u help me?

Comment: I don't know, because I cannot take a view on your server.